# Insert a text file containing logs into a SQLite database

Tags: ios, ios5, logging, sqlite

I had use a method to redirect all my logs into a text file. The problem is that i do not know how to store the text file into the SQLite database.

Comment: You have to store the content of your text file, not file itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Blob fields. [here](http://effbot.org/zone/sqlite-blob.htm) is a description how to do it. And of course the content of the file should be stored. The file itself can be stored elsewhere, with a HTTP POST...

Comment: I am using this method to upload my logs to a log file.. 
Is it possible to redirect all to a SQLite database?


- (void) redirectConsoleLogToDocumentFolder
 {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *logPath = [documentsDirectory 
    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Testingg.log"];
    freopen([logPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
 }

Comment: that isn't uploading, but is a file save. Upload it requires network and you will upload via HTTP or FTP to a server, you are just storing in a local storage with that method

Comment: Ok so is it possible to save the current logs into a database?

Comment: yes, I gave a link, where it shows how to put the content of that file into a Blob field in database.